# How to extract all articles in subcategories recursively using dbPedia?

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I need to extract information about articles (e.g., abstract, thumbnail) which located on the different nested subcategories of given category (e.g., History).
How can I do that using SPARQL query? Or what is the optimal way to do that on python with a few SPARQL subqueries?

Comment: For example, I'm interested in History category. This category has subcategories, each subcategory has subsubcategories and so on. And I want to retrieve all articles from different level of subcategories for History.


PREFIX dct:<http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT   ?x   
WHERE { ?x dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History>
}

Comment: Please edit your question and put the query (Markdown formatted there) - not in a comment

Comment: Sub-categories can be retrieved by using the `skos:broader` resp. `skos:narrower` relation. Note, you should limit the depth of traversal as it might be too expensive if the category hierarchy is too big

Comment: In addition to using approporiate predicates in your **SPARQL query**, it's helpful to use the right class names in your **SO question**.  I think you are looking for things that are `skos:narrower*` than `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History>`, which is a `<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept>`, not a "category"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This gets all `?sc` "subcategories" that are recursively (or transitively) narrower than "History", up to a depth of 3.  I implemented that with the `{minDepth,maxDepth}` notation that Virtuoso understands.  Other triplestores may not understand it.  I have also added English-language filtering on string literals, while still retaining triples with IRIs for `?o`.

```
SELECT ?sc ?lab ?p ?o 
WHERE {
  ?sc skos:broader{1,3} <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History> .
  optional {?sc rdfs:label ?lab  } .
  ?sc ?p ?o 
  filter (lang(?lab) = "en")
  filter ((lang(?o) = "en") || isURI(?o))
}
```

Additionally, that query reports all of the triples with `?sc` as the subject. I didn't see any abstracts (using `<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>` as predicate?) or any thumbnail relationships.  You can confirm that by projecting only `distinct ?p`, or even counting:

```
SELECT ?p (count(?p) as ?pcount)
WHERE {
  ?sc skos:broader{1,3} <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History> .
  optional {?sc rdfs:label ?lab  } .
  ?sc ?p ?o 
  filter (lang(?lab) = "en")
  filter ((lang(?o) = "en") || isURI(?o))
} 
group by ?p
order by desc(?pcount)
```

If you do deeper recursion, you will find some abstracts.  But the deep recursion is slow and I feel like I'm conceptually missing something.

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?sc skos:broader{5,7} <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:History> .
  ?sc <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?a 
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, indeed. One comment, you should mention that using `property{n, m}` in a property path is non-standard SPARQL syntax and just an extension of Virtuoso. It was discussed in the [submission phase](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/) but unfortunately never made to the official [W3C recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths). Cheers

Comment: Thanks! The first query is very to close to goal. How can I add a filter for "en"? The column "p" contains values with "@en", but last column contains rows for different language at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  What do you mean the "p" column contains values with "en"?  p is the predicate, not a language-typed literal.  I have updated the answer to show filtering on ?lab and ?o.  note that this will hide ?sc ?p ?o relationships in which ?o is an IRI, as opposed to a literal.  For example, that might hide URLs for thumbnail images.

Comment: @AKSW Is there a W3C standard for transitivity limits?  I could swear I've used it with triplestores other than Virtuoso, but maybe my memory is bad.  This notation is certainly better than `OPTION ( TRANSITIVE, 
             t_distinct, 
             t_in(?s), 
             t_out(?o),
             t_min (1), 
             t_max (4)...)`

Comment: Indeed this notation would be better and more compact than the one which is Virtuoso specific - but there isn't something in the standard as far as I know. I know that some other tools also allow for this extension, but this depends on the triple store. For example, Jena also has some ARQ extension for htis feature, see https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/property_paths.html